# Set HDMI for 7'' display fails on Pi4

Tags: pi-4, hdmi

Trying to run [Waveshare](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/7inch_HDMI_LCD_(C)) 7'' display on my Pi4. According to Waveshare manual I should set params manually in config.txt:

```
[all]
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 1024 600 60 6 0 0 0
hdmi_drive=1
```

Unfortunately I can't see whole screen. Only top, bottom and left side is visible. Touchscreen is hitched. When I press most top left corner few centimeters down and few centimeters right is affected.

How to solve this problem?

When I connect the same display to Pi3 everything goes fine.

Comment: what does this mean? ... `touchscreen is hitched`

Comment: Only top, bottom and left side is visible. Touchscreen is hitched. When I press most top left corner few centimeters down and few centimeters right is affected.